# JQuery validation addClassRules

Tags: jquery, validation

When I validate a form with JQuery Validation class rules, only the first input field passed validation and others do not validate.

I have made an example in jsfiddle that can be seen here below:
http://jsfiddle.net/GrhBr/37/

If I do it the normal way it works, see example below:
http://jsfiddle.net/WNMUL/29/

Greetz Chiel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add name attribute to each field and it'll work fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/GrhBr/46/

Comment: Thanks for this, Vikk. I was having the same problem and this was the reason. I would have expected it to work with just the id defined, but indeed it seems name is required for validation to work correctly. Thanks.